# how to convert [('US', 144), ('CA', 37)] to ['US', 'CA']

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df with customer and country data. I want to count the countries so can find the top5 countries, and them use that as a filter elsewhere.

this gives me the counts

```
countries = collections.Counter(responses_2021['country'].dropna())
```

that yields this

```
[('US', 144), ('CA', 37), ('GB', 15), ('FR', 15), ('AU', 12)]
```

and this gives me the top 5

```
countries_top5 = countries.most_common(5)
```

now I need to transform it into a more simple structure so I can do my filter (here i'm just typing it manually because that's the only way I could move forward lol)

```
options = ['US', 'CA', 'GB', 'FR', 'AU'] 
rslt_df = df[df['country'].isin(options)]
```

So, to get from the this

```
[('US', 144), ('CA', 37), ('GB', 15), ('FR', 15), ('AU', 12)]
```

to this

```
['US', 'CA', 'GB', 'FR', 'AU']
```

I started by trying to remove the counts

```
countries_top5_names = np.delete(countries_top5, 1, 1)
```

but that yields

```
[['US'], ['CA'], ['GB'], ['FR'], ['AU']]
```

so now I'm trying to flatten that, but I don't know how.

better way?

SOLUTION (thanks to @dan04 below)

```
countries_top5_names = [x[0] for x in countries_top5] 
rslt_df = df[df['country'].isin(countries_top5_names)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take element `[0]` of each tuple.

```
>>> data = [('US', 144), ('CA', 37), ('GB', 15), ('FR', 15), ('AU', 12)]
>>> countries = [x[0] for x in data]
>>> countries
['US', 'CA', 'GB', 'FR', 'AU']
```

Comment: brilliant. it works. I'll accept. thank you so much. I think I need to take more classes...

Comment: should I improve the title? how would you describe the request so that others may mor easily find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try more universal method to do this.

```py
data = [('US', 144), ('CA', 37), ('GB', 15), ('FR', 15), ('AU', 12)]
groups = list(zip(*data))
print(groups[0])
print(groups[1])
```

Output:
('US', 'CA', 'GB', 'FR', 'AU')
(144, 37, 15, 15, 12)